# Kettle Join Rows - Closest Element Larger than x

Tags: pentaho

Using pentaho kettle (also known as pdi), I have a "Join Rows (cartesian product)" step which merges two streams of data.

Both the first and second stream have a numeric value attached. For example,

```
Stream 1 - Values 1, 3, 5
Stream 2 - Values 2, 4, 6
```

I want to join the two streams to get the following output:

```
(1, 2)
(3, 4)
(5, 6)
```

I would describe the correct output as having stream 1 pick the smallest value which is larger than the value from stream 1.

Within the Join Rows step, I can specify stream 2 having a value greater than the stream 1 value. Unfortunately, this produces the following incorrect outcome:

```
(1, 2)
(1, 4)
(1, 6)
(3, 4)
(3, 6)
(5, 6)
```

Is there a different step that I should use instead of "Join Rows" in Kettle? Or am I missing a setting on the join rows step?

Note: I also looked at using a Stream Lookup step, but it only works for equals and not for my logic.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already half way there.

- You have two inputs: Stream1 (1, 3, 5) and Stream2(2, 4, 6)
- You join rows (make sure you sort them before joining) on value(stream2) > value(stream1)
- You sort resulting stream on {value(Stream1), value(Stream2)
  This gives you

> ```
> (1, 2)
> (1, 4)
> (1, 6)
> (3, 4)
> (3, 6)
> (5, 6)
> ```

- Put the "Add Value Fields Changing Sequence" step and set the "Init
  sequence if value of the following fields change" to value(Stream1).
  Resulting stream is:

> ```
> (Stream1, Stream2, result)
> (1, 2, 1)
> (1, 4, 2)
> (1, 6, 3)
> (3, 4, 1)
> (3, 6, 2)
> (5, 6, 1)
> ```

- Put a filter step and filter on "result=1".
- Resulting stream from "true" branch of the filter is the deisired result.

I uploaded "example.ktr" with the solution (I used Kettle 4.3. version):

[example.ktr](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B_C8tdbiOkEARF9jUnVNNlNBUFU)